# Change user id of an app on Android

Tags: android, linux, root, userid

I have root. So how can I change the user id of an android app? The background is, I have to start an activity of an app not owned by me in my app. But this will only work if the apps have the same user id.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can run the activity of the other app as `root` by starting the other app's `Activity`, using the `am start` command, and run the `am start` command as `root`.

See the following places:

- [Launch an app through adb shell](http://www.android.pk/blog/general/launch-app-through-adb-shell/)
- [Launch a script as root through adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761992/launch-a-script-as-root-through-adb)

So in the end you would be doing something like `Runtime.exec("su -c \'am start....\'")