# running busybox through a .bat using java

Tags: java, android, batch-file

I am trying to execute ls command through busybox.
I am creating a .bat file to execute this command which i am calling through .java

However, i am not able to execute commands one after another in .bat file.

This is the contents of my .bat file

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\Some Directory\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" shell
/data/busybox/busybox ls
```

what i think that once i start the shell through the first line of my .bat, the control from the shell is lost hence second command is not executed.
Because if i write my .bat file as

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\Some Directory\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" shell ls
```

it works fine.

I need to write commands in my .bat file so that they exceute one after the another.
I have tried using CALL before each commands in .bat, still it does not work.
I have tried to use multiple .bat, still a fail cause.

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9418553/1531054

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this myself with ADB at this moment, but this works for other programs that have an input buffer.  I will try to verify this tonight, but if anyone else confirms it before then, leave a comment.

```
@echo off

(   echo shell
    echo /data/busybox/busybox ls
) | adb.exe
```