# getting error while using "su" command

Tags: android, linux, adb, su

I try to make batch file to run adb commands. I want to use `su -c`, but I get the error:

```
 su: invalid uid/gid '-c'.
```

I saw somewhere that my `su` version doesn't support `-c`, how can I enable this?

Answer (score 19):

In batch file it should be like this:

```
adb shell "su 0 <command args>"
```

For example:

```
adb shell "su 0 mount -o rw,remount /system"
```

Comment: 0 is uid for root

Answer (score 2):

The standard Android `su` is much simpler than its regular `linux` counterpart. It does not support any commands other than `-c` - so it's become redundant.

[`usage: su [UID[,GID[,GID2]...]] [COMMAND [ARG...]]`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.c)

Comment: Somehow, as I said, my 'su' doesn't support even '-c'. (I use Android)

Comment: `su -c 'command args'` becomes `su 0 command args` in Android

Comment: ok. so if I want to run commands (using batch script) from a wanted and specific path in my devices, how can I do it without it?

Comment: @AlexP. do you know what 0 means here?

Comment: @AlirezaA.Ahmadi 0 is the user ID you want to run the command as, so 0 for root.