# Android Run script in ADB shell

Tags: android, shell, ssl

I am trying to fallow [this tutorial](http://wiki.pcprobleemloos.nl/android/cacert) in order to install SSL certificate on Android emulator.

I need to start the emulator from command line, so I run

```
emulator -avd myDevice -http-proxy myIp:8888
```

After device is started I want to copy my certificate file from PC to the device, so I run those commands

- `mount -o remount,rw /system`
- `cp /sdcard/5ed36f99.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/`
- `cd /system/etc/security/cacerts/`
- `chmod 644 5ed36f99.0`

I bundle them all together using [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9418553/1129332)

The final command looks like this:

```
adb shell su -c 'mount -o remount,rw /system; cp /sdcard/5ed36f99.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/; cd /system/etc/security/cacerts/; chmod 644 5ed36f99.0'
```

But I am getting an error:

> su: invalid uid/gid '-c'

If I do it from the shell it works, but then when I restart the emulator it restore the system to previous state without saving my changes.

How can I solve those two problems?

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/su/su.c).? I think in android `SU` command is not as same as the Linux one.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I try, tnx. My bigger problem is that all the data is gone when emulator is rebooted